# Hexbin scatter plot between two 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((10,10))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3.2))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(ar)
```

In the code above, I can visualize a 2D numpy array. I want to plot a scatter plot (hexbin) between two 2D numpy arrays. How do I extend this code to do that?

--EDIT:

```
arr_a
    [[2, 3]
    [3, 4]]

arr_b
    [[3, 5]
    [4, 6]]
```

As an example, in this case we have 2 numpy arrays, arr_a and arr_b. A scatter plot between the 2 arrays will compare them point by point. The point by point comparison should look like this:

```
2   3
3   5
3   4
4   6
```

and the resulting scatter plot should look like this:
[image]

Comment: do you mean:        http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html

Comment: yes, but it needs to work in the case I have outlined in my question

Comment: It may be perfectly clear to you what "plot a scatter plot (hexbin) between two 2D numpy arrays" means; but I fear everyone else does not understand this phrase at all. You can position a plot between other plots (spacially) or you can use operations between arrays. But what does "between" mean for a plot and an array?

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have added an edit to the question to address your comment. In summary, I want to compare individual elements which are at the same position of the 2 numpy arrays.

Comment: Still unclear. The two arrays are the same, so what would you expect the comparison to look like. Even if they were not the same, what would be the result of the comparison and how should the comparison look in a plot?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest modified with a better example and a scatter plot. I could not make a hexbin plot because not sure how to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the [documentation of `hexbin`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) and also [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html) one needs to provide two 1D arrays of same length to `plt.hexbin(x,y)`. 
You can get those from 2D arrays by using `numpy.flatten()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n = 66
a = np.ceil(np.random.standard_normal((n,n))*n)
b = np.ceil(np.random.standard_normal((n,n))*n)+6.

plt.hexbin(a.flatten(),b.flatten(),gridsize=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
n = 66; m = 4
a = np.ceil(np.random.standard_normal((n,n))*m)
b = np.ceil(np.random.standard_normal((n,n))*m)

hb = plt.hexbin(a.flatten(),b.flatten(),mincnt=1)
plt.colorbar(hb)
plt.show()
```

[image]